# Write png graph file from Stata to Excel

Tags: excel, stata

I'd like to create graphs in Stata and to export the underlying graph data (not the raw data from which they were produced) to Excel, altogether with the graph file. I think I stick to the official code documentation on `putexcel` by StataCorp (http://www.stata.com/manuals14/pputexcel.pdf), but I keep getting the following error message:

```
picture: expression must be enclosed in ()
```

When I enclose the relevant code line in parentheses I get the error

```
unknown function picture()
```

Any advice or hint on that? See below for a ready-to-run code sample.

```
sysuse auto, clear
* ------ place for some data manipulations (snip) -----------

tempfile data
save `data'

* plotting
graph bar price foreign
graph export "test.png", replace

* Export plot data (works only w/o by-option in graph command)
serset use
export excel "graphdata.xlsx", sheet("test") firstrow(variables) sheetreplace
putexcel H20 = picture(test.png) using "graphdata.xlsx", sheet("test") modify
serset clear

* re-use original data and plot next graph
use `data', clear

*...
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want:

```
sysuse auto
export excel using "myresults.xlsx", replace sheet("Data")
graph bar price foreign
graph export "test.png", replace
putexcel set "myresults.xlsx", sheet("Graph") modify
putexcel A1 = picture(test.png)
```

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, thanks for your effort. Unfortunately, your code doesn't work for me: I still get the same eroor messages as with my original code. I'm beginning to suspect it has something to do with my Stata installation. Thanks, nevertheless. Think, I'm gonna ask the Stata staff,

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved thanks to a hint by the Stata staff. For the records, it was an issue of which version of Stata's `putexcel` should be used (I didn't use the latest version -- sorry for having you bothered with my self-made problem). Now I'm going for `putexcel` version 2.1.1, 12aug2016 and the below code does perfectly what it is meant to do (you can find out your version of `putexcel` with `which putexcel`):

```
sysuse auto, clear
* ------ place for some data manipulations (snip) -----------

tempfile data
save `data'

* plotting
graph bar price foreign
graph export "test.png", replace

* Export plot data (works only w/o by-option in graph command)
serset use
export excel "graphdata.xlsx", sheet("test") firstrow(variables) sheetreplace
putexcel set "graphdata.xlsx", sheet("test") modify
putexcel H20 = picture(test.png)
serset clear

* re-use original data and plot next graph
use `data', clear

*...
```